# Ember: Error while processing route: not defined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

Not seeing what I'm missing to cause 'Posts' template to be rendered blank in the browser. My other templates are rendering as normal.

I'm getting the error:

`Error while processing route: posts posts is not defined ReferenceError: posts is not defined`

My route file:

```
Blogger.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return posts;
  }
});
```

View:

```
  <ul>
    {{#each}}
      <li>{{title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

Index calling the store.js file with the posts, my router, and 'posts' in the template loader:

```
  <script src="blogger.js"></script>
  <script src="router.js"></script>
  <script scr="store.js"></script>

  <script src="controllers/about.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/contact.js"></script>

  <script src="routes/posts.js"></script>

  <script>
    EmberHandlebarsLoader.loadTemplates([ 
      'posts', 'about', 'contact', 'phone', 'email', 'application'
    ]);
</script>
```

In my store.js file:

```
var posts = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: "title text",
    body: "body text"
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'title text two',
    body: "lorem ipsum"
  }
];
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6ndtbLq/2/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work at all. Route defined twice, etc...

Comment: Apologies, first time using both Ember and using jsfiddle for more than just a two file application. Not sure exactly what to put in but was requested to add a jsfiddle. @denis.peplin

Comment: The jsfiddle should be runnable except for the part that is causing errors for you. It's hard to help if we can't see what is happening. Based on this fiddle, I'd say your problem is "you didn't load Ember?" but I'm sure that's not what is happening on your computer.

Comment: Try jsbin.com, maybe it'll be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error that `posts` is not defined, and in your `store.js` file it clearly says `var posts = ...`, the first thing to check is that `store.js` is being loaded properly. Your script tag says `<script scr="store.js"></script>` - if you fix your typo from `scr...` to `src`, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just from the code in this sample, the variable `posts` in

```
model: function() {
  return posts;
}
```

is never defined. Which is why the browser is telling you `ReferenceError: posts is not defined`